# C#/EF6: How to perform multi-threaded load test without EF error

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

**The Setup**

I develop an MVC web app on top of EF6. To perform some maintenance tasks, I have a separate console application with access to the same code base where I can do scripting and generally put a level of safety between me and direct data manipulation.

**What I Want to Do**

Certain errors in the web application only manifest under load from many users (peak would be about 300 concurrent users). I would like to run a multi-threaded test with all threads performing data- and calculation-intensive tasks to simulate something closer to full load.

**My Code**

Here's my code to run the tests:

```
public static void LoadTest(int durationInSeconds, int maxThreads)
{            
    //Create a collection of threads with its associated request data. Each MiscRequest has
    //its own context and contains all the test methods.
    var threads = new List<Tuple<Thread, MiscRequest>>();
    Report.ReportLine("Beginning load testing...");            

    //while the test is stil running...
    var endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(durationInSeconds);
    while (DateTime.Now <= endTime)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("\rThread Count: {0} - Time Remaining: {1}", threads.Count().ToString(), (endTime - DateTime.Now).ToString()));
        //clean out any old threads
        threads.RemoveAll(t => !t.Item1.IsAlive);

        //start a new thread if there is room
        while (threads.Count() < maxThreads)
        {
            //create the request using the default connection string for the new context                    
            MiscRequest request = new MiscRequest(DEFAULT_CONNECTION, true);

            //attach that method to a thread and kick it off
            var t = new Thread(GetTestMethod(request));
            t.Start();

            //store the thread and the context
            threads.Add(new Tuple<Thread, MiscRequest>(t, request));
        }

        //pause a bit for the threads to work
        Thread.Sleep(LOOP_WAIT_TIME_MS);
    }

    //finish up all the work
    threads.ForEach(t => t.Item1.Join());
}
```

When I run this method (with > 1 thread), EF generates an error: *System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll Additional information: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.*

I thought I might try checking whether the dbcontext was initialized before moving to the next thread as I read that initializing multiple context concurrently could produce this error, but I can't find any way to determine whether the context has been initialized.

**My Question**

My web application manages to accomplish what I want to do, allowing each user to call these methods without causing an issue.  How can I replicate that functionality, or somehow allow multiple data writes in a way that doesn't cause EF to throw a fit?

Comment: Each test method should probably create its own context, rather than having a context shared for the whole application. It works in your web application because (presumably) the context is not static, and is created for each request

Comment: I have edited the code to create a new context for every thread rather than sharing a context; however, I receive the same error:

_An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Additional information: The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe._

Comment: Edited the question to show new multi-context approach, even through it's not working.